# Bitlocker failure after installing Visual Studio 2015 update 3

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

Today I installed Visual Studio 2015 update 3. After installing, I did a reboot, as asked, and subsequently wasn't able to initiate Windows.

After the motherboard POST, when it comes to the screen with the bitlocker password prompt, nothing appears except the background color blue. After several seconds the PC shuts down.

I moved the disk to another PC and Windows recognises the disk as encrypted but I can't open because it always says that the password entered is incorrect and the recovery key doesn't belong to the disk.

Any hints of what to do?

Comment: There isn't much else you can do.  If you cannot decrypt the HDD with the recovery key, beause the machine that encrypted will not POST, you are out of options.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. The other PC to which I connect the disk to has Windows 7 so I thought that it could have some incompatibility with a disk encrypted with Windows 10. So I got a spare drive, connected it to my computer, installed Windows 10 and I was able to decrypt the disk. So, I still don't know what happened but learnt that in order to decrypt a bitlocker disk one needs the exact same version which it was encrypted with.

Comment: You don't but most versions of Windows 7 don't actually have Bitlocker, only Enterprise and Ultimate